# Optimal algorithm for a "round robin" doubles tournament?

Tags: co.combinatorics, partitions

Side note: so far neither Bard nor ChatGPT has managed to do this correctly, even when I show the errors.

I have 4N players ( N = 4 or N = 5 suffices) and want to set up three rounds of play.  In each round, there will be N games played (four players per game).  I want to set up the groupings so that no two players appear together more than once, regardless of whether they are teammates or not.
Is there a reasonably simple non-exhaustive search algorithm that will set up these rounds for me?
The first round, of course is easy:
(16 players, each row is the players in one game)
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12
13,14,15,16
To clarify: in a given round, every player is in one of the foursomes.  All games (foursomes) are played simultaneously in a given round.

So in the second round,  player 1 must not be in the same game as any of 2,3,4 ;and so on.    I can't tell whether the [Hungarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) or [Round Robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_item_allocation) algos  can't do this or just that the "AI" software can't do it correctly.

**Another thought**
Based on an external suggestion; not sure this holds in all cases.
First divide the players into two equal sets.  It's relatively easy to create unique pairs for the rounds in each of these "brackets." Then any combination of pairs from BracketA with pairs from BracketB will yield the groups of four that I'm looking for.  Is this valid?

Comment: Isn't it like Euler's 36 officers or Kirkman's schoolgirls problems?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem

Comment: @HassBoyouk  yes - thanks!  This is Kirkman if I have 4N school girls in groups of 4 but only for 3 days.    Looks like an ugly problem (Steiner) in general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $N=5$ and more generally $N$ relatively prime to $6$, it is easy to make $N$ rounds.

Name the players $(i,j)$ for $0 \leq i \leq 3$ and $0 \leq j \leq N-1$. In the $a$-th round, take the elements of the $b$-th quadruple to be $\{ (0,b \bmod N), (1,a+b \bmod N), (2, 2a+b \bmod N), (3, 3a+b \bmod N) \}$.

Suppose, to the contrary that $(i_1, j_1)$ and $(i_2, j_2)$ play together in both rounds $a$ and $a'$. Since $(i,j_1)$ and $(i,j_2)$ never play in the same round, we must have $i_1 \neq i_2$. Then the equation that $i_1$ and $i_2$ play together in round $a$ says that $j_1 - a i_1 \equiv j_2 - a i_2 \equiv N$ and, likewise, $j_1 - a' i_1 \equiv j_2 - a' i_2 \bmod N$. So $(a-a') (i_1 - i_2) \equiv 0 \bmod N$. But $i_1 - i_2 \in \{ \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3 \}$ and $\text{GCD}(N,6)=1$, so this implies that $a=a'$. $\square$

---

A more pictorial description. I'll use bridge instead of tennis, because the 4-sides of a table make for good nomenclature. Arrange $N$ bridge tables in a cricle. At each of $N$ tables, let one player sit at north, one at east, one at south and one at north.

After the first set of games, the north players stay put, the east players move on one table, the south players move on two tables and the west players move on three table, each staying in their same position (north, east, west or south). Repeat this $N$ times.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the same problem?  I want three 'rounds' , such that in each round everyone is playing in one of the 4-tuples.  My "N" represents the number of 4-tuples playing in each of 3 rounds.  (maybe generalize to M rounds of play later?)

Comment: So take the first three of these rounds. As I understand it, the conditions are that (1) all $4N$ players play each round and (2) no two players play together in two different rounds. If you can solve that for $M$ rounds, than you automatically get a solution for any smaller number of rounds.

Comment: close, but no 2 players on the court, partners OR opponents, in multiple rounds.   My intent is to have as mixed-as-possible "social tennis"  set up.

Comment: Right. No two players are in any quadruple more than once.

Comment: I'm sorry for being fogged here, but what is the meaning of the first element in each pair of your b-th quadruple?  Don't you need to adjust those values `0:3` for each of the N rounds?   if `b ==1`, then I see the second elements as 1,2,3,4 .     I have players 0 <= i <= 15  , for example.

Comment: I am numbering the $4N$ players as $(i,j)$ for $0 \leq i \leq 3$ and $0 \leq j \leq N-1$.

Comment: That still fails to meet the requirements;  I need 4N players in **each** round.  Thus , if it helps,  a total of  3 * N games in 3 rounds;  no duplications in any of those 3*N games.

Comment: In each round, there are 4 quadruples. In the first round, they are the $N$ quadruples of the form {(0,b), (1,b), (2,b), (3,b)}. In the second round, they are the $N$ quadruples of the form {(0,b), (1,1+b), (2,2+b), (3,3+b)}. In the third round, they are the $N$ quadruples of the form {(0,b), (1,2+b), (2,4+b), (3,6+b)}. Etcetera.

Comment: I followed your Bridge Game example for 16 players.  If the North players are 1,2,3,4 East are 5,6,7,8, South are 9,10,11,12 , then in the second round, North 1  is again matched with South 11.   Similar failures occur in East & West.   I think your algorithm works only for odd numbers of tables, or as you said, relatively prime with 6 (which 4 is not).